# Remove icon from jpeg image

Tags: image, image-processing, recovery, hexdump

Is there any way to remove icon from image that in original didn't had the icon.

Maybe with help of hexdump or something?

Here is an example of image.

[image]

is there a way to remove the heart icon from it?

*I don't really need this image it is just for example

Comment: What would you replace it with?  Everything under the icon has been erased, there's no way to know what should go there.

Comment: @MarkRansom ok that was my question, is there a way to return back what was under the icon, so you say there are 100% no way to return the data under the icon back?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use color thresholding to obtain a binary mask which can be used to isolate the desired regions to keep. Once we have this mask, we bitwise-and to effectively remove the heart

---

After color thresholding with a HSV lower and upper range, we obtain this mask

[image]

To remove the heart, we invert the mask which represents all regions in the image that we want to keep then bitwise-and with the input image. Since you didn't specify what you want to replace it with, I've just colored the removed region with white. Here's an implementation using Python and OpenCV

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 138, 155])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
invert = 255 - mask
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=invert)
result[invert==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but that was not the actual question, see my comment to Mark Ransom

Comment: @MaksimNovikov, there is no way to return what was "originally" underneath. You can look at [image inpainting](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_inpainting/py_inpainting.html)